# Why I cannot create a new document library and set the ootb contenttype "ArticlePage" as default?

Tags: 2013, office-365

I am using Office 365 and creating a SharePoint 2013 online website. I am trying something simple:

1. Create a document library.
2. Go to the Settings and enable Content Type Selection.
3. Add the OOTB content type "Article Page".
4. Remove the default content type "Document".
5. Now I have only 1 content type in the document library, which is also the default one.
6. I try to create a new item by clicking in the ribbon on "New Article Page".
7. I get a popup with some fields like Title, Description, Page-layout.
8. I fill in some dummy values and select the layout "(Article Page) Image on the left".
9. Now I get an unexpected error.
10. I also get this error with the other page layouts.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think this article has the answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803712/sharepoint-second-page-library 
Seems it's only the default Site Pages library that allows you to add the article page, and there is only one Site Pages library per site. You'll have to create a sub site.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can create the page in the system library, then move it to a new library in the site. I've run into this same scenario where I needed to change permissions on a set of pages so I created a new library to hold those pages.

To move it back to the pages library, you will need to be in windows explorer as the Pages library doesn't show as a destination when moving using the SP interface.